# Python Error: local variable 'last_card' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

The program keeps on telling me that 'last_card' is referenced before the assignment and it is. However, how can I by pass this error. If you look at the code, last_card is referenced in the first if statement. I want to use its value from the first "IF" statement and use it in the second. How can I do that?

```
if region == "showCardHistory":
        temp = re.search(r'Card History for Slot (A|B|\d+)(.*)',line)
        if temp:
        last_card = temp.group(1)
        temp = re.search(r'Secs since boot\s+:\s+(\d+)',line)

if temp:
    card_slot_string = re.match(r'(A|B)',line)," CPM ",last_card,":"," IOM ",last_card
```

Comment: Do you have some `line` input strings?

Comment: Could you indent your code?

Comment: Yes, the line input, is a file of strings

Comment: @ThamerMatar: Provide some sample strings.

Comment: Chuck just answered why, it is giving me an error because the first if statement is sometimes not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't know for sure that the 1st `if` clause will be called. So, in order to be safe, it will assume at compile-time that last_card hasn't yet been declared. When you reference it in your 2nd `if` clause, the case may happen that the 1st `if` clause didn't evaluate `True`, and then it will have an UnassignedError.